# How can I remove a part from an URL using Java

Tags: java, regex, url

What I get:

```
116:part-of-the-url-for-deep-link
```

What I need:

```
part-of-the-url-for-deep-link
```

(remove the number and :)

Thank you!

Comment: Just for the record: Tool.MY_TOOL, that is an enum?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `String::split`

```
String got = "116:part-of-the-url-for-deep-link";
String want = got.split (":")[1];
```

Comment: And to be sure, don't forget to protect with if ( got.split (":").length > 1 )